# changing color glutWireSphere in animation in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

i want to change a wireSphere during an animation with openGL.
But it won´t work.
What must i do that it changes a color during an animation?

So far i only have this :

```
   glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0); //yellow color
   glutWireSphere(0.5,60,50);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me. Here's a minimal GLUT program that uses your code, and successfully displays a yellow sphere on my Mac:

```
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

static void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glutWireSphere(0.5f, 50, 60);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("WireSphere");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect that there's some state you're setting outside the code you copied that prevents this from working for you. But it's hard to speculate what that could be. I think you'll need to post more code, or at least be more specific about the unexpected behavior than "it won't work".

Comment: I understand that, my question was that i want different colors for one WireSpere. For example: glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0); //yellow color
   glColor3f(0.0,1.0,1.0); glColor3f(1.5,1.5,1.5);

Comment: different colors in a gluWireSphere ?